# Disable hostname checking for SSL connections?

Tags: java, http, ssl, https, clojure

I'm using clojure-http to make the following POST:

```
(clojure-http.resourcefully/post "https://android.apis.google.com/c2dm/send"
  {"Authorization" (str "GoogleLogin auth=" auth-token)}
  {"registration_id" registration-id
   "data.msg" "blah"
   "collapse_key" "blah"})
```

And getting this exception:

```
java.security.cert.CertificateException: No subject alternative DNS name matching android.apis.google.com found.
[Thrown class javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException]
```

For some weird reason, about 10% of the time I **don't** get the exception and the request goes through.

I believe it's an issue with Java's host name checking on SSL connections*, so my question is, how do I disable that from Clojure? (or is that a bad idea security-wise?)

Thanks,
Wei

*deduced from this post and others like it: http://www.jroller.com/hasant/entry/no_subject_alternative_names_matching

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its not a problem with your code, its a problem with android's website.

Open this link in a modern browser- https://android.apis.google.com/. You will see that the SSL certificate belongs to `*.google.com`, but you are visiting a domain under `*.apis.google.com`. You should probably search on Android forums for a solution to this problem.

Its a bad idea to disable host name checking, you are opening up yourself to man-in-the-middle attacks. If you don't really care about security, you might as well use http, its easier than disabling host name checks.

Comment: Thanks! Didn't realize I could get by (for now) using just http. I'm planning to leave a message on the Android mailing list asking them to fix their SSL certificate.